# libiconv-2.dll missing when running shp2pgsql

Tags: postgis, postgresql, shp2pgsql

My system is Windows 7 with PostgreSQL 9.4 and PostGIS 2.2.

I'm running **shp2pgsql** program from command line (cmd window, not PSQL interface).

```
shp2pgsql "D:\file.shp" schema.table > file.sql
```

I'm getting the following error message (sorry this is in french but it says *System error: the programme cannot start for libiconv-2.dll file is missing on the computer. Try to reinstall the program in order to fix the bug*):

[image]

I have then completely reinstalled PostgreSQL 9.4 and PostGIS 2.2. The `libiconv-2.dll` is properly installed inside the bin directory (C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin). I don't understand why this file is not found on the computer and I don't know what else I could do...

Comment: Is that the exact command you are running, or are you running it using path references? It sounds like your working directory (and PATH) aren't the same as the executable.

Comment: I run the program from inside `bin` directory (same problem when I run `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\shp2pgs.exe" "D:\file.shp" schema.table > file.sql`.

Comment: make sure it's the same dll...does the spelling match exactly? Is there a hyphen in the dll you have?

Comment: Are you using 32-bit 9.4 or 64-bit 9.4? Only thought I have is maybe something up with the permissions on the dll you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answer my own question based on my comment to @Artec answer.

The issue apparently came from `libiconv-2.dll` file had been installed in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\postgisgui` whereas `shp2pgsql.exe` is stored in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin`.

It seems that the executable is looking for the DLL inside its own directory. I may be wrong, but copying `libiconv-2.dll` file inside `bin` did bring the solution...

Comment: Copying the `libiconv-2.dll` into the `bin` folder also helped when getting just a basic `the application was unable to start correctly` error message trying to start the `shp2pgsql ` command. Win10, PostgreSQL 9.4, PostGIS 2.2

Answer (score 2):

Look at portable version postgis and unzip files to ex. C:\Postgis

[Postgis](http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg90/buildbot/)

Nextly copy `libiconv-2.dll` to `C:\Postgis\bin` (libiconv-2.dll you can find in QGIS installation). Put `.shp, .dbf, .shx` files to `C:\Postgis\bin` and run your command `C:\Postgis\bin>shp2pgsql "Test.shp" schema.table > file.sql`. Use simple shp filename. In result:

> Shapefile type: Polygon
>
> Postgis type: MULTIPOLYGON[2]
>
> file.sql is created

Works on W10 64 bit, I think that it should works on W7 64 bit to.

Comment: Thanks for this answer that made me trying to change the DLL directory. The `libiconv-2.dll` file was in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\postgisgui`. I tried to move the file to `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin` and it eventually worked fine... I did not need to copy the QGIS directory version of the DLL.

Comment: Then good luck.